# Curses Behavior Erasing window box

Tags: python, curses

I'm trying to write a simple CLI python text editor using curses module that comes with python. I have everything set up correctly on my Windows 10 box and can do all the tutorials without issue.

I draw in the order, the screen, and windows on the screen with a border less than the screen. Create a window using the border measurements that are in 2 rows, columns in from the outside of the screen. Then I define a text area and create a subwindow.

If I exclude the subwindow, a border is drawn and the cursor placed inside the border. But when I try to save the text by gathering it the text includes the border. So, that is the reason for the subwindow. If he box is larger than subwindow why would the border disappear.

Here is the code:

```
import curses
import traceback

from curses.textpad import Textbox, rectangle
from pathlib import Path


def draw_menu():
    pass

def edit_mode(window):
    textbox = Textbox(window)
    textbox.edit()

    return textbox.gather()

def main(screen):
    """
    Get the screen size and set a border around the text area.
    Reset the cursor to the top of the text area.
    """

    # get the current screen size
    y_max, x_max = screen.getmaxyx()
    ymin_border, xmin_border, ymax_border, xmax_border = \
        2, 2, y_max-2, x_max-2
    ymin_textpad, xmin_textpad, ymax_textpad, xmax_textpad = \
        ymin_border+1, xmin_border+1, ymax_border-1, xmax_border-1

    # draw the windows and box around it. Place cursor at beginning of 
    # the edit area
    window = curses.newwin(ymax_border, xmax_border, ymin_border, xmin_border)
    window.box()

    # if this line is excluded I see the box but then the box is saved input
    text_box = screen.subwin(ymax_textpad, xmax_textpad, ymin_textpad, 
                             xmin_textpad)
    window.addstr(ymin_textpad, xmin_textpad, "")
    screen.refresh()

    text = edit_mode(text_box) # right now drop user into edit mode

    return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    buffer = ""
    try:
        screen = curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        buffer = main(screen)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()
        print(f"Saved Buffer to Screen\n{buffer}")
    except:
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: What is the question?